# Использование отрезка времени в Android

Tags: android, время

Подскажите как сделать следующее, Toast должен показаться только в том случае, если кнопку успели нажать 3 раза за 5 секунд.

Answer (score 2):

```
  System.currentTimeMillis();
```

на телефоне не проверял, но по идее должно работать

Comment: работает, с уверенностью могу сказать